# Built android app crashes on startup with java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, react-native, expo, runtimeexception

Our clients are reporting back these errors and we are unable to reproduce them.

The error on google play console is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2981)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3042)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1639)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6780)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1500)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1390)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at host.exp.exponent.c.a.a (NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:108)
  at host.exp.exponent.c.a.b (NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:100)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.a.onCreate (BaseExperienceActivity.java:83)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity.onCreate (ExperienceActivity.java:160)
  at host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity.onCreate (ShellAppActivity.java:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6948)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2924)
```

The crash happens on startup.
The crash happened 13 times on a `Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 8.0 (gts28lte), Android 7.0`.

General info:

- The app was built with [Expo](https://expo.io/)'s SDK 31
- The apk was generated with `expo build:android --release-channel prod`

What could cause this crash?

If there is any other info I could provide, please let me know!

Update-2019-02-06:
React Native's start Activity onCreate method:

Path: `./node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java`

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

Comment: We need to see the code in the start activity's OnCreate method before we can help.

Comment: I updated the post as you asked.